# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: n.factory is not a function TypeError: n.factory is not a function

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, build

My ionic 6 (angular) app is running as expected on an Android simulator when running in debug mode. However when I generate the aab it gives an error I don't understand. The same happens if I launch the app with ionic cordova run android --prod

```
main.737916f90481aca1.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: n.factory is not a function
TypeError: n.factory is not a function
    at $d.hydrate (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:455563)
    at $d.get (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:454139)
    at $d.get (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:454187)
    at Ay.get (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:478835)
    at _a (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:437674)
    at Da (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:438151)
    at Object.Cs (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:465938)
    at M.component.e.ɵfac [as factory] (4987.e5c5c75110c5e2ce.js:1:3444)
    at Vo (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:439842)
    at hy (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:481079)
    at X (polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:17774)
    at X (polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:17309)
    at polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:18614
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:8389)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.737916f90481aca1.js:1:516776)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:8310)
    at v.runTask (polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:3448)
    at A (polyfills.c13b04107186556f.js:1:10775)
```

Following my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ecove",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.9",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^6.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/diagnostic": "^6.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/network": "^6.1.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/safari-view-controller": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/status-bar": "^6.1.0",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.4.2",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/core": "^6.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova": "^11.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.4",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^7.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "node-js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^8.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.9",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.6.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "cordova-android": "^10.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROIDX_VERSION": "1.0.0",
        "ANDROIDX_APPCOMPAT_VERSION": "1.3.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": {},
      "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

Any help will be welcomed. Thanks.

I have revised dependencies and all seems to be well configured.

Comment: why are you using cordova? use Capacitor, 2nd you are using capacitor plugin in cordova i doubt that is the issue. try remove all capacitor plugins.

Comment: I have discovered the problem, after adding all providers in each @NgModule it works. The question now would be why this worked right on debug mode and why it did not give any compilation error.